# propagate angular object function call to an internal object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, call

Is there some elegant way to propagate angular object function call to a same function but on internal object?

this is what I have now

```
var grid = $('#' + config.selector).w2grid(gridConfig);

angular.merge(this, {
   addData: addData,
   lock: lock,
   unlock: unlock,
   reload: reload,
   clear: clear,
   removeRow: removeRow,
   getRecord: getRecord,
   setRecord: setRecord,
   refreshRow: refreshRow,
   destroy: destroy,
   resize: resize,
   setData: setData,
   selectNone: selectNone,
   getSelection: getSelection
});


....

    function addData(data) {
        grid.add(data);
    }

    function lock(message) {
        grid.lock(message || '', true);
    }

    function unlock() {
        grid.unlock();
    }

    function reload() {
        grid.reload();
    }

    function clear() {
        grid.clear();
    }
```

and I would like to have only overriden grid functions

```
var grid = $('#' + config.selector).w2grid(gridConfig);


    ....

        function addData(data) {
            alert('add data overide');
        }

    ....
```

so when `angularObject.reload()` function is called it will invoke `grid.reload()` and if `angularObject.addData()` is invoked, it will call overridden function `addData()` within angular object.

Answer (score 0):

out of the box propagation is quite a thing I miss from JavaScript but you can do it by hand

```
    function InnerClass() {
         this.method = function() {

         }
    }

function OuterClass() {
    var decoratedClass = new InnerClass()

    this.method = decoratedClass.method.bind(decoratedClass)
}


var instance = new OuterClass
instance.method()
```